# Create Scroll to top button in Angular material 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-material-5

```
<button mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_up</mat-icon>
  </button>
```

How to create scroll to top button in angular material 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add an event click and use JavaScript to scroll to top:

```
<button mat-icon-button (click)="window.scrollTo(0, 0);">
<mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_up</mat-icon>
</button>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp

Comment: you should add the click event to the button not the icon

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer only works if the window is the element which is scrollable. So for example, if you have some other scrollable element on the page, `window.scrollTo(0,0)` will do nothing.

Instead you need to get the element like so,

`@ViewChild('element') element: ElementType`

And in the template you should have an element with this on it

`<div #element></div>`

then run `this.element.nativeElement.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});`